# how can export data in excel file custom plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, export

below is my code  I need to  export data with excel  file

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?page=client_plugin" method="post" name="export_excel">

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button type="submit" id="export" name="export" class="btn btn-primary button-loading" data-loading-text="Loading...">Export MySQL Data to CSV/Excel File</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

    <table class="dash-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Client Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Health Condition</td>
            <td>Changes</td>
            <td>Image</td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        foreach ($results1 as $key => $value) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value->rclient_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $value->email;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $value->health_condition;?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $value->changes;?></td>
                <td><img src="<?php echo  $value->image;?>" width="50px" height ="50px"></td>

            </tr>

        <?php } ?>

    </table>

    <?PHP if(isset($_POST["export"])) {

     foreach($results1 as $value) {
    //foreach($row as $name => $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $line .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $line);

    // remove the result pointer back to the start
    //mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

    // and loop through the actual data
     foreach($results1 as $value) {

        fputs($fp, $value);

    }

    fclose($fp);
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    readfile('export.csv'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/client/jquery.js"></script>
<button id="excel" onClick ="$('#dataTable').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});">  XLS</button>

<button id="print">Print me</button>
<table class="dash-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10px" border="0" id="dataTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Client Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Health Condition</td>
        <td>Changes</td>
        <td>Image</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach ($results1 as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value->rclient_name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo  $value->email;?></td>
            <td><?php echo  $value->health_condition;?></td>
            <td><?php echo  $value->changes;?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo  $value->image;?>" width="50px" height ="50px"></td>

        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

</table>


 <script src="<?php echo plugins_url();?>/client/tableExport.js"></script>    

 <script type="text/javascript">

//table2excel.js
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    var pluginName = "table2excel",

    defaults = {
        exclude: ".noExl",
                name: "Table2Excel"
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
            this.element = element;
            this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
            this._defaults = defaults;
            this._name = pluginName;
            this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var e = this;

            e.template = {
                head: "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>",
                sheet: {
                    head: "<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>",
                    tail: "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>"
                },
                mid: "</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>",
                table: {
                    head: "<table>",
                    tail: "</table>"
                },
                foot: "</body></html>"
            };

            e.tableRows = [];

            // get contents of table except for exclude
            $(e.element).each( function(i,o) {
                var tempRows = "";
                $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i,o) {
                    tempRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
                });
                e.tableRows.push(tempRows);
            });

            e.tableToExcel(e.tableRows, e.settings.name);
        },

        tableToExcel: function (table, name) {
            var e = this, fullTemplate="", i, link, a;

            e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
            e.base64 = function (s) {
                return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
            };
            e.format = function (s, c) {
                return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                    return c[p];
                });
            };
            e.ctx = {
                worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
                table: table
            };

            fullTemplate= e.template.head;

            if ( $.isArray(table) ) {
                for (i in table) {
                    //fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "{worksheet" + i + "}" + e.template.sheet.tail;
                    fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "Table" + i + "" + e.template.sheet.tail;
                }
            }

            fullTemplate += e.template.mid;

            if ( $.isArray(table) ) {
                for (i in table) {
                    fullTemplate += e.template.table.head + "{table" + i + "}" + e.template.table.tail;
                }
            }

            fullTemplate += e.template.foot;

            for (i in table) {
                e.ctx["table" + i] = table[i];
            }
            delete e.ctx.table;

            if (typeof msie !== "undefined" && msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
                    //use blobs if we can
                    fullTemplate = [fullTemplate];
                    //convert to array
                    var blob1 = new Blob(fullTemplate, { type: "text/html" });
                    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, getFileName(e.settings) );
                } else {
                    //otherwise use the iframe and save
                    //requires a blank iframe on page called txtArea1
                    txtArea1.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                    txtArea1.document.write(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                    txtArea1.document.close();
                    txtArea1.focus();
                    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, getFileName(e.settings) );
                }

            } else {
                link = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                a = document.createElement("a");
                a.download = getFileName(e.settings);
                a.href = link;

                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.click();

                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    function getFileName(settings) {
        return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls";
    }

    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
        var e = this;
            e.each(function() {
                if ( !$.data( e, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                    $.data( e, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                }
            });

        // chain jQuery functions
        return e;
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );


$("#excel").click(function(){

                        $("#customers").table2excel({
                              exclude: ".noExl",
                        name: "Excel Document customers"
                        }); 

                         });

function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("dataTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('#print').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
 </script>
```